# Как поставить изображения колонкой именно boostrap4 классом?

Tags: css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Как поставить изображения колонкой именно boostrap4 классом

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRNBj6p6w3IFHTy8KRGntqbyaYauKshoTfvNTV95fMBYTFszIw36g" alt="" class="">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRNBj6p6w3IFHTy8KRGntqbyaYauKshoTfvNTV95fMBYTFszIw36g" alt="" class="">
    </div>
  </div>



  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Во первых внутри `.row` всегда должна быть `.col*`. Это принцип построения сетки бутсрапа, иначе на пограничных размерах у вас появится горизонтальный скролл.

Чтобы использовать колонку по всей ширине, используйте `.col-12`.

Для того, чтобы изображение не выходило за пределы колонки, добавьте ему класс `.img-fluid`.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRNBj6p6w3IFHTy8KRGntqbyaYauKshoTfvNTV95fMBYTFszIw36g" alt="" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRNBj6p6w3IFHTy8KRGntqbyaYauKshoTfvNTV95fMBYTFszIw36g" alt="" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```